# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException only occurs on my pc

Tags: spring, jsp, maven

I'm getting the error below, this project is running on my colleagues computer but it's not working on mine.

The previous versions of our project was working on my computer and also included beans.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'springSecurityService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityService' is defined
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:326)
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/" />

<!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/views/test.jsp -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine"> 
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" /> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"> 
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" /> 
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
<context:component-scan base-package="en.irp.projectName" />

<!-- Load properties -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:projectName.properties" />

<!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="en.irp.projectName.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="268435456"/> <!-- 256 megs -->
</bean>

<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Internationalization & Localization -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/languages/global</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
</bean>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="springSecurityService" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<!-- Session configs -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some code, XML configurations, which will help us solve your problem.

For the error its clear, spring not able to find Bean named 'springSecurityService'.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityService' is defined
```

---

I do see that  you are referring "springSecurityService" in your "spring-security.xml"

```
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="springSecurityService" >
    <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

However , As I can see you have no where defined the Bean/Service named "springSecurityService" like

```
<bean id="springSecurityService" class="..."> </bean>
```

Do you have annoation based configurations? I think yes because `<mvc:annotation-driven />` ? can you show us code how have you defined Bean "springSecurityService".

The problem is Spring is not able to find the specified bean "springSecurityService" in Spring context.

Comment: your sample xml still doesn't have data related to "Security".. show your configurations related to security. isue exists in that configuration. your application not able to fin Bean named "springSecurityService" so either your missing dependency jar which has  annotated class for  "springSecurityService" or missing configuration.

Comment: Made another edit, added web.xml and spring-security.xml